# In pytest, how to assert if an exception (which is inherited from a parent exception class) is raised?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, exception, pytest

**What I have done** :

I have a function def `get_holidays():` which raises a `Timeout` error. My test function `test_get_holidays_raises_ioerror():` first sets `requests.get.side_effect = IOError` and then uses `pytest.raises(IOError)` to assert if that function raises an `IOError`.

**What the issue is** :

Ideally this should fail, since my actual `get_holidays()` does not raise an `IOError`. But the test passes.

**Possible reason** :

This might be because `Timeout` is inherited from the `IOError` class.

**What I want** :

Want to assert specifically if `IOError` is raised.

**Code** :

```
from mock import Mock
import requests
from requests import Timeout
import pytest

requests = Mock()

# Actual function to test

def get_holidays():
    try:
        r = requests.get('http://localhost/api/holidays')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.json()
    except Timeout:
        raise Timeout

    return None

# Actual function that tests the above function

def test_get_holidays_raises_ioerror():
    requests.get.side_effect = IOError
    with pytest.raises(IOError):
        get_holidays()
```

Comment: You don't have to add anything, the test is already good to go. `requests.get()` actually raises an `IOError` because of assigned `side_effect` but it is not caught in `get_holidays()` (as you probably would think) because you are only expecting a specific subclass of `IOError` - the `Timeout`, passing the base class and all its other impls along. The base `IOError` is thus correctly caught in `pytest.raises(IOError)`. So the test is correct - if you expect it to fail, it is a sign of an error in code.

Comment: So you mean if I set `side_effect=IOError` and assert `pytest.raises(Timeout)` , the assertion should fail, since the exception in assertion is the child class of raised exception and not the other way round?

Comment: Exactly. BTW `except Timeout: raise Timeout` in `get_timeout()` - is it intentional?

Answer (score 0):

pytest captures the exception in an `ExceptionInfo` object. You can compare the exact type after the exception.

```
def test_get_holidays_raises_ioerror():
    requests.get.side_effect = IOError
    with pytest.raises(IOError) as excinfo:
        get_holidays()
    assert type(excinfo.value) is IOError
```

Comment: The answer is not wrong, but the additional assert has the same effect as an `assert True`. `pytest.raises(IOError)` will fail the test if another exception or no exception is raised, so the assert line won't be reached anyway. If you want to test for exceptions subclassing `IOError`, the assert will be reached, but will duplicate the type check already made in `RaisesContext`.