# Pytest: check if specific exception is raised (and fails if parent exception is raised)

Tags: python, exception, pytest

Coming from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160323/in-pytest-how-to-assert-if-an-exception-which-is-inherited-from-a-parent-excep), it seems that is not possible with pytest to check if a specific exception is raised: if you mention the parent exception, the test passes as well.

I made this little example to illustrate, all three tests passed just fine. I expect only one to pass.

Could you confirm ? Should I check the excinfo ?

(Why is this a problem? The function I was testing can, in some cases, return a true `TypeError` exception, and I'd like my tests to detect precisely when one or the other is raised)

Thanks

```py
import pytest

class CustomExc(TypeError):
    pass

def a_random_function():
    raise CustomExc

def test_random_function1():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        a_random_function()

def test_random_function2():
    with pytest.raises(CustomExc):
        a_random_function()

def test_random_function3():
    with pytest.raises(BaseException):
        a_random_function()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomExc` is both a `TypeError` and a `BaseException`, so this is expected behavior. The raised exception is checked for its type using `isinstance`, which means that all base classes will also pass.

If you want to test for a concrete exception, and *not* any derived exception, you have to do the check yourself. As you mentioned, you can check the exception info:

```py
def test_random_function():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError) as e:
        a_random_function()
    assert e.type == CustomExc
```